# How could i parse this HTML using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing

I want to parse HTML using Jquery

I am getting some HTML from server as responseText like this :

```
<html>
   <title>Title</title>
   <body>
     <p>My JSON data</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Now i want to parse this using jquery parseJSON function, How could i do this plz help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you make the server output proper JSON in the first place?

Comment: But, this isn't JSON. This is HTML. Are you sure you want to parse HTML as JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply create a jQuery object with the responseText, it will return a representation of the content in the body of your responseText, e.g.

```
var jqobj = $('<html><head></head><body><p>Meep</p></body></html>');
var text = jqobj.html();   // returns "Meep"
```

Then you can parse it.

Answer (score 3):

`parseJSON` is for parsing `json`

if you are getting a valid html from the server then you can apply jquery's simple DOM traversal methods to it and get the desired object, or you can also use

[`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

to parse the html if it contains some non standard html tags